# jQuery UI Slider: Change HTML Based on Value

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

I'm having an issue generating a line of HTML text based on the values of two inputs: a radio button selection and the value of the slider. My example is only partially working at present. When I set the slider position to 2000, and then change my radio button selection, the appropriate text appears. However adjusting the slider again does not affect the result that appears until selecting another radio button. I'd like the result to generate on any input change.

Any advice is much appreciated! https://jsfiddle.net/mL8j0g5w/4/

```
<div id="slider"></div>
<input type="text" id="amount">

<input type="radio" id="traffic1" name="traffic" value="Test 1">
<input type="radio" id="traffic2" name="traffic" value="Test 2">
<input type="radio" id="traffic3" name="traffic" value="Test 3">
<input type="radio" id="traffic4" name="traffic" value="Test 4">

<p>Results: <span id="result-1"></span></p>

<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $( "#slider" ).slider({
    value:    1000,
    min:      1000,
    max:      3000,
    step:     1000,
    slide:  function( event, ui ) {
      $( "#amount" ).val( ui.value );
    },
  });
} );
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input').on('change', function() {

  if ($('#amount').val() === '2000' && $('input#traffic1').is(":checked")) {
    $('#result-1').html('Value 1');
  }
  else if ($('#amount').val() === '2000' && $('input#traffic2').is(":checked")) {
    $('#result-1').html('Value 2');
  }
  else if ($('#amount').val() === '2000' && $('input#traffic3').is(":checked")) {
    $('#result-1').html('Value 3');
  }
  else if ($('#amount').val() === '2000' && $('input#traffic4').is(":checked")) {
    $('#result-1').html('Value 4');
  }
  else {
    $('#result-1').html('');
  }

  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: what do you mean by "I'd like the result to generate on any input change."? Can you give an example on which part you think is not working?

Comment: At a guess, if the text input changes with a slider change, it's not being triggered. And that's proper -- programmatic changes don't trigger the onChange behaviours, by default. In my example below, though, it does. ;)

Comment: @eliellel The test that appears in the #result-1 span should change whether a different radio button is selected, or the slider moves. Right now the change only takes place AFTER you move the slider, and then select a different radio button.

Comment: Small suggestion? Rather than using multiple `$("input#trafficN").is(":checked")` references, simply get the value  like this: `$("[name='traffic']:checked").val()` and do a compare like you do for the val of `$("#amount")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I'd look at simplifying your code with a switch/case, and the only bit you're missing is that, when you move the slider and you programmatically change the input, you also need to trigger the change event. Otherwise, it seems like you're close! I've included a snippet, and tried to comment -- but ask if it doesn't make sense.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // create the jQueryUI slider
  $("#slider").slider({
    value: 1000,
    min: 1000,
    max: 3000,
    step: 1000,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      // Here's the missing bit:
      $("#amount")
        // show the value...
        .val(ui.value)
        // ... and tell the DOM it's changed.
        .trigger("change");
    },
  });
  // When any input is changed, run my func.
  $('input').on('change', showResult);
});

var showResult = function() {
  // set some variables, rather than creating the same reference many times...
  let amount = $("#amount").val();
  let trafficVal = $("[name='traffic']:checked").val();
  let resultEl = $("#result-1");

  // First, are we at the middle range?
  if (amount === '2000') {
    // We ARE. Now, do something based on the selected radio value.
    switch (trafficVal) {
      case 'Test 1':
        resultEl.text("Value 1")
        break;
      case 'Test 2':
        resultEl.text("Value 1")
        break;
      case 'Test 3':
        resultEl.text("Value 1")
        break;
      case 'Test 4':
        resultEl.text("Value 1")
        break;
        // in the event of NO radio selected...
      case 'default':
        resultEl.text("");
    }
  } else {
    // We are NOT in the mid range. Blank the result field.
    resultEl.text("");
  }
}
```

```css
#slider {
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="slider"></div>
<input type="text" id="amount">

<input type="radio" id="traffic1" name="traffic" value="Test 1">
<input type="radio" id="traffic2" name="traffic" value="Test 2">
<input type="radio" id="traffic3" name="traffic" value="Test 3">
<input type="radio" id="traffic4" name="traffic" value="Test 4">

<p>Results: <span id="result-1"></span></p>
```

Comment: You've filled in the blanks for me. Thanks so much!

Comment: Glad to help. It's a bit of a gotcha to have to manually trigger the change, but it does make sense. sort of. ;)

Answer (score 1):

It will be better if you create one function to apply all the changes (`checkChange()`), and in the sliders [`slide`](https://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-slide), you call it.
Changed all your `if` to `switch`, and the `cases` to each radio `id`.
Added one `key up` to trigger whenever you type in the `#amonut` input.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
 $( "#slider" ).slider({
  value:  1000,
  min:    1000,
  max:    3000,
  step:  1000,
  slide:  function( event, ui ) {
   $( "#amount" ).val( ui.value );
      checkChange(); //call function at every slide
  },
 });
  $('input').on('change', checkChange); //create function when inputs change
  $('#amount').on('keyup', function(){
    $("#slider").slider("value", $(this).val()); //if you type in the input field, it will change slider value, too
  });
} );

function checkChange() {
  var value = ''; //value of the result
  
 if($('#amount').val() === '2000'){ //check, first, if the value is 2000
  
    var selectedId = $('input[type="radio"][name="traffic"]:checked').attr('id'); //return the selected radio id
    
    switch(selectedId){ //used switch to change 'var value' content
    
      case 'traffic1':
        value = 'Value 1';
        break;

      case 'traffic2':
        value = 'Value 2';
        break;

      case 'traffic3':
        value = 'Value 3';
        break;

      case 'traffic4':
        value = 'Value 4';
        break;

      default:
        value = '';
    } 
    
  }else{
  
   value = '';
    
  }
  
  $('#result-1').html(value);//change Result html
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js">
</script>
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="slider"></div>
<input type="text" id="amount">

<input type="radio" id="traffic1" name="traffic" value="Test 1">
<input type="radio" id="traffic2" name="traffic" value="Test 2">
<input type="radio" id="traffic3" name="traffic" value="Test 3">
<input type="radio" id="traffic4" name="traffic" value="Test 4">

<p>Results: <span id="result-1"></span></p>
```

Comment: My only issue with this approach is that the slider now has to be aware of multiple moving parts. Not that this is a wrong approach, I don't think it is, but IMHO, it makes more sense to tell the dom that the input has changed, and let the functions that are watching for input changes handle it. This way, the code stays a little more loosely coupled. Good solution, though.

Comment: Thanks! But... multiple moving parts?

Comment: In your example, the slider has to be aware of the checkChange function. If later on the name of the function were to get changed, you'll need to remember to update that both in the input handler AND the slider. If, instead, the slider simply triggers the text input to scream "HEY! I GOT CHANGED! EVERYBODY!!!! ANYBODY?!?!", then the slider doesn't care about who's listening. It becomes 'agnostic' of the rest of the functionality, letting the change handler do its thing. Basically, it means that the checkChange() is only being called in a single place.

Comment: Rereading that, it sounded a little silly. I really need to cut back on the coffee.

Comment: No, don't need to care that much about it! It's always good to see things with other eyes. But what I've tried here is to leave the things like "What to do?", "What is the best way?" to the one who asked. I know it's way better to have only one function call, but I was trying to give the freedom to use this and all the other functions you need/want to the slider. For that reason I've added one keyup to `#amount` too. :)
***Note**: Coffee is never too much. :P*